# What the heck is wrong with this png file?

Tags: android, png, imagebutton

So I have a simple small PNG file with a transparency on it. I have it setup as a ImageButton and it will not display the image at all. I'll swap it with a different one with the exact same size and dimensions (different name) and it displays normally. I then tried changing the name of this PNG, no luck. I resaved the PNG as a PNG, still no luck. I tried using the PNG in a ImageView in a different activity. For whatever reason, Eclipse will display it fine but not in the emulator or handset.

Just some quick info: The pngs are in Photoshop, I use the Save for Web and Devices to save the PNG-24 with transparency on both images.

Question is, why? Here are the files: add.png does not work, but the search.png does.

[image]

[image]

Comment: FWIW, I grabbed them and threw them in psp to compare, nothing of note that I could see.  (There's no EXIF or meta data, which might have been stripped by imgur, not that it would matter much)  Perhaps post your XML?

Comment: Super annoying... what makes this PNG so friggin special that it doesn't want to display? I checked my XML and it's fine, because I just swap the drawable and it still gives me crap. I'll run the clean function and see if that does anything.

Answer (score 0):

I used your add PNG in an ImageView and it worked perfectly fine. Sometimes cache can cause these weird anomalies with Android, as I have experienced it often with images. You can try deleting the \bin\resources.ap_ file and \bin*.apk file, then rebuild your project and it should resolve.